# Make a function call before any trigger in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick

I want to make a button using onclick handler that will call the function once before any trigger.

In React I can do like this

```
<button onClick={clickHandler()}></button>
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in pure Javascript?

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

And for the run once thing, elsewhere, simply call myFunction()… once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the function just have to return another one.

```
let button = /* your button */;
button.addEventListener('click', (function(){
    /* logic before any trigger */
    return function(){
        /* logic for every trigger */
    }
})());
```

Alternatively, you just run whatever code before attaching the handler:

```
let button = /* your button */;
/* logic before any trigger */
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    /* logic for every trigger */
});
```

Same logic for both scenarios:

```
let button = /* your button */;
function myButtonLogic(){
   /* logic for everything */
}
myButtonLogic();
button.addEventListener('click', myButtonLogic);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I have done the alternative before, but the problem is the logic is the same, so is there any efficient way to do that?

Comment: If it's the same then it's better to just put that logic into a function, call it before the handler and then just attach the handler.